# PHP How to autoload the global namespace alias defined in the class file

Tags: php, namespaces

In some namespace there is defined a class with the static method. To make names shorter I use shorthand alias for this method. The alias is defined in the global namespaces.
There occurs problem with autoloading. The alias cannot be used until the class is loaded.

Example.
Assume following structure

```
composer.json
index.php
src/
   Utils/
      Dumper.php
```

File `src/Utils/Dumper.php` defines class `MyVendor\Utils\Dumper` and also defines alias `_d()` in the global namespace

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\Utils {
  class Dumper 
  {
    public static function show($x) 
    {
       echo "<pre>" . print_r($x, true) . "</pre>";
    }
  }
}

namespace {
  if ( !function_exists( '_d' ) ) {
    function _d() 
    {
      $_ = func_get_args();
      return call_user_func_array( 
        array( 'MyVendor\Utils\Dumper', 'show' ),
        $_
      );
    }
  }
}
?>
```

File `composer.json` creates PSR-4 autoloader.

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyVendor\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot use the alias `_d()` since there is no requirement for class `Dumper`.
The code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head> <meta charset='utf-8'> </head>
<body>
<?php 
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use MyVendor\Utils\Dumper;

$arr = array(10, 20, 30);

//Dumper::show($arr);
_d($arr);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

causes `Fatal error: Call to undefined function _d() in index.php on line 13`

There is an obvious solution. Once the `Dumper` is used, it has to be autoloaded, so entire `src/Utils/Dumper.php` is included and also alias is made.

```
Dumper::show($arr);
_d($arr);
```

But that is not my point. 
Anytime I move my `Utils` package to another projects I would have to remember to use `Dumper::show()` for the first time. 
Any other user must also be aware of this obstacle.

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with something like the composer 'files' functionality, and move out that shorthand `_d()` function to for example a `bootstrap.php` in the package root.

Example usage:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "files": ["src/MyLibrary/functions.php"]
    }
}
```

See https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files